# HTTP header field containing the filename for an uploaded file

Tags: http

Suppose I'm sending a file on my disk called *foo.txt* using the `POST` verb, I can set its size in the `Content-Length` header field. Is there a way to specify its name too? Because I want to use the same name when I receive it and save it on the server. Or should I use a custom header field? Something like `File-Name`.

Comment: What content type do you use? If you're using `multipart/form-data` the filename is sent in the content-disposition section in the body and can be picked up by the server accordingly.

Comment: I'm not using HTML.

Comment: [RFC 6266 Content-Disposition header in HTTP: 4.3 parameter 'filename'](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6266#section-4.3) (although it's 'usually' for download)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I knew about it, but it seems like it's used when a server send a file to the client, not sure if it's used the other way around.

Comment: 6266 3 says it's '**usually** ... origin server [to] user agent'. If they meant 'only', they wouldn't have said 'usually'.